# How to apply role to user in Dreamfactory?

Tags: rest, dreamfactory

Making first steps with Dreamfactory and followed the tutorial I am not finding, how could I apply role to the user, when I want user to access some service (and not app).

Here
http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Tutorials/Accessing_SQL_tables
is described, how to create such role, but on User-tab there is no place to apply roles for services, there is only list of apps.

How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'll do my best to explain

- Access to services is always controlled by Roles. You can have as many or as few Roles as you like.
- Apps (API Keys) *can* have a default Role, but it is not required.

  - If the app has a default Role, then no JWT is needed to access. The call is made with API Key only, and the default Role is used to allow or deny access to services.
  - If the app does NOT have a default Role, then a user session (JWT) needs to be included in the call, in which case the User and App are correlated to a Role, and that Role is used to allow or deny access to services. A User may have a different Role for each App.
  - Assigning the user to app to role relationship is done via the User management tab.

So with that in mind, you need to create a role that defines access to your desired services. Then you need to assign that role to the user for a particular app (api key.) Then when you make your api calls you will make them with the user's session and the api key included, and the role will allow or deny access to services as you defined it.

Comment: I can create a service (which is not part of any app). I can create role to access that service. But I can't apply this role to user, because the service is not part of the app. How to accomplish that?

Comment: access is determined by user + api key + role. It's a 3 way relationship. Look at the user's Role tab. He can have a different Role for every App. If you're wanting to incorporate access to a particular service to app that already has a role defined for that user, then you should simply modify the Role to allow access to the service.
Otherwise, just use a different api key and make you new independent role correspond to that App for the user.

Comment: Like in DF forum, it is not trivial to understand, that empty App gives the missing piece to bind user with service. At least for me. Please incorporate this information into answer (and into documentation, if possible).